# Extension method for nullable Enum from string

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums

I am converting Enum of one class to Enum of another class via the code below:

```
var someClassA.MyEnumA = (MyEnumA)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumA), someClassB.MyEnumA.ToString());
```

I was finding myself repeating this block of code quite often so I wrote a helper method like below:

```
    public static T EnumFromString<T>(string value)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
    }
```

The usage then in the same line above is:

```
var someClassA.MyEnumA = EnumFromString<MyEnumA>(someClassB.MyEnumA.ToString());
```

This works nicely.  However I now have code where I can have nullable Enum.  So my current code is:

```
                if (someClassB.MyEnumX.HasValue)
                {
                    someClassA.MyEnumX = (MyEnumX)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumX),someClassB.MyEnumX.ToString());
                }
```

I am not sure of how to update my current helper method to handle both scenarios - or would it be simpler to just write another helper method  called NullableEnumFromString - I am not sure how that would work or even be possible with Generics though?

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is the type of the property _MyEnumA_ in SomeClassA and _MyEnumA_ in SomeClassB?

Comment: can't you check `value` and return null if `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` in your helper method?

Comment: To handle nullable enums you want to use the type `<T?>` and the constraint `where T : struct`

Comment: Also (and additional to the other comments) you will have to conceptually work out what you want to do with null? how does that map? are you just going to use the default, or you going to specify a default.

Comment: @Jonathan The OP would then just have to keep in mind that ToString() cannot be called on a null value. Thus, the OP would have to first check whether the MyEnumX property is null before attempting to perform a ToString() operation.

Comment: @Ruan: `Nullable<T>` overrides `ToString` and returns `""` for the "null" state. It won't throw NRE.

Comment: Why not use `someClassA.MyEnumX = someClassB.MyEnumX;` instead? Why is mapping via string required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the main issue here is that by the time you call the conversion method, you've already converted the enum value to a `string`, and so you have no way to know what the original type was, never mind handle a nullable enum type.

It also seems inconvenient to me just from the point of view of making all the callers have to call `ToString()` themselves.

You could improve on both aspects by writing two different extension methods, one for the regular enum type and one for the nullable version:

```cs
public static TResult Convert<T, TResult>(this T value)
    where T : struct, System.Enum
    where TResult : struct, System.Enum
{
    return (TResult)Enum.Parse(typeof(TResult), value.ToString());
}

public static TResult? Convert<T, TResult>(this T? value)
    where T : struct, System.Enum 
    where TResult : struct, System.Enum
{
    return value != null ?
        (TResult?)Enum.Parse(typeof(TResult), value.ToString()) : null;
}
```

Notes:

- The above uses C# 7.3 feature that allows a constraint to `System.Enum`. If using an earlier version of C#, just omit that. It will still work, but simply won't have the same degree of compile-time type safety.
- While all four type parameter constraints specify `struct`, strictly speaking that's only necessary for the second, nullable-enum version. It doesn't hurt anything in the first version; I just put it in for consistency.
- This nullable-enum extension method returns `null` if the input value is `null`. Your question doesn't say what value you would use in that case. You can use whatever fallback you like, if that's not what you meant to do.